# Which of two parameters was chosen for a sample?

Tags: chi-squared-test, goodness-of-fit, geometric-distribution

Problem: $X$ is chosen to be $\text{Geom}(p_1)$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and is otherwise chosen to be $\text{Geom}(p_2)$. Given a sample of size $n$ from $X$, guess whether $p_1$ or $p_2$ was chosen and give a *consistent* percentage confidence. (For instance, if you make $m$ guesses with 70% confidence, asymptotically $0.7m$ of them should be correct and $0.3m$ should be incorrect.) In this context, $\mathbb{P}(\text{Geom}(p)=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$.

A naive solution is to guess $\text{True}$ always with percentage confidence 50%, but we want a problem solution which maximizes the percentage of correct guesses.

I think a good solution is a one-sample $\chi^2$-test in which I look up the $p$-value associated with $\Sigma_i \frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$. In the case of $p_1$, $O_i$ is the number of samples with value $i$ and $E_i=np_1^{i-1}(1-p_1)$ (the geometric pmf multiplied by the sample size). From the two $p$-values $x,y$, for $p_1$ and $p_2$ respectively, I think $x/(x+y)$ is the likelihood that $X=\text{Geom}(p_1)$, by the definition of conditional probability.

If the sample's largest value is $j$ then I'm currently aggregating the data into $j$ groups, for values $1,2,\dots,j-1$ and $\ge j$. And I'm then looking up $\chi_{j-1}^2$, the distribution with $j-1$ degrees of freedom.

However, this approach is not working for me, perhaps because this doesn't work well for large values, which have small $E_i$s. For instance, if I try $p_1=0.4,p_2=0.3,n=10$ then one random test selected $p_1$ and gave the sample $1,1,1,1,2,2,2,5,9,13$, but I get a small (1.4%) chance that $p_1$ was chosen, I think because the test is highly skewed by $13$, which it thinks is incredibly much more likely to come from $p_2$. Or maybe because of all the zero $O_i$ values (for $3,4,6,7,8,10,11,12$). These high-confidence wrong guesses occur too often in testing (i.e. it is wrong when it has 99% confidence more than 1% of the time).

Is this a good statistical test to use and, if so, how can I group the data (programmatically) or otherwise adjust the calculations to make my percentage confidence consistent?

EDIT: I know you can calculate the probability of the sample occurring in each case exactly e.g. $\mathbb{P}(\text{sample of size}\ 7\ \text{is}\ 1,1,1,1,2,2,8)=\frac{7!}{4!2!1!}\mathbb{P}(\text{Geom}(p_1)=1)^4\mathbb{P}(\text{Geom}(p_1)=2)^2\mathbb{P}(\text{Geom}(p_1)=8)$.

But I think this would become computationally difficult for very large sample sizes.

Comment: Are all the $X_i$'s chosen with the same random $p_j$ or is there a different choice for each $X_i$, which would make the distribution a mixture?

Comment: All $X_i$s from the same $p_j$.